# How to show/hide a child QWidget with a motion animation?

Tags: python, animation, qt4, pyqt

I am working on an application with two children. One's a widget that functions as a toolbar, the second, below, functions as dashboard, on which information would appear. The latter can be shown/hidden with buttons on the former. [Here's a screen-cast of the prototype](http://videobin.org/+51n/5fl.html).

Now I am looking at doing the same but with a motion animation whilst showing/hiding the lower widget.

**In short:** the effect should be giving the impression the entire application rises or falls progressively when toggling the dashboard.

**In details:** I would like the height of the lower widget to decrease until it is reduced to 0 and then hidden completely. Likewise it would increase slowly when showing the widget again. In the meanwhile the position of the application should change accordingly so it stays at the bottom of the screen.

How can I do that? I've never done animations on Qt before. If you don't have an answer, do you know of a quality tutorial that could lead me there.

*NB: I am using PyQt.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can get what you want by using a [QPropertyAnimation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qpropertyanimation.html#details) that animates the geometry property of your widget.
But IMHO this is the window manager's role to do what you want. Maybe you will have some headaches bypassing it (but I'm maybe wrong).

After better reading of your question, it seems that you want to use your own components to trigger the hiding/showing so the WM shouldn't be a problem.

As a start here is some code that animate a minimizing of a widget (assuming `tbw` is an instance of the widget you want to animate):

```
formerGeometry = QtCore.QRect(tbw.geometry()) # storing previous geometry in order to be able to restore it later

hideAnimation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(tbw, "geometry")
hideAnimation.setDuration(2000) # chose the value that fits you
hideAnimation.setStartValue(formerGeometry)
#computing final geometry
endTopLeftCorner = QtCore.QPoint(tbw.pos() + QtCore.QPoint(0, tbw.height()))
finalGeometry = QtCore.QRect(endTopLeftCorner, QtCore.QSize(tbw.width(), 0))
hideAnimation.setEndValue(finalGeometry)

hideAnimation.start()
```

Comment: thanks :) 1. The example's in C, I can't read that but will try something 2. If my animation concerned the entire window I could imagine the WM taking care of it. But since the animation concerns a child widget, would that still be the case you think? If so how would you suggest to do so? (NB: destination platform is Linux).

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I will try to implement that. I accept the answer already--assuming this will work fine :) Cheers.

Comment: OK it worked fine--but laboriously. I cheated a little bit though :P To hide the lower widget, I move the entire window below the desktop line first and then toggle the lower widget off. That avoids applying two effects simultaneously: one to change the widget's size, the other to move the main window accordingly.
I was surprised the finalGeometry was *relative* and not absolute. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hello again. I think I need a little more help if you don't mind :| I've tried to invert the situation (button below and slide above). To do that I had to make two animations: one to reduce the height of the slide, another to reduce the height and move the main window down y axis by the height of the slide. [Here is the code](https://gist.github.com/1156262) Here are two screen-casts: 1. [effect on slide only](http://videobin.org/+51x/5g8.html), 2. [effect on both slide and main window](http://videobin.org/+51y/5g9.html).

Comment: As you can see: the first needs the window to slide down, and the second's not reducing the size of the slide completely and bothers the height of the button. Is this a layout problem you think? Any tips would be welcome (I find sizes layout etc on Qt very confusing). Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe setting `setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Ignored)` to the label of your dashboard (just before triggering the animations) will solve your problem. You should also remove the two calls to `layout.setSizeConstraint(QtGui.QLayout.SetNoConstraint)`

Comment: You did it again! ... now I need to figure out what just happened :P

Comment: There's a good tutorial here: http://zetcode.com/pyqt/qpropertyanimation/